# How to get SAML Response from SAML Request?

Tags: php, security, curl, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to log into a system which has SAML authentication set up. I'm using cURL in PHP to redirect to the authentication page, sign in the form, and return back to homepage. So far, I am able to login successfully to the form but redirecting back to the homepage uses a POST request: **SAMLResponse** and **RelayState**.

I already have the **SAMLRequest** token and **RelayState** from when the session originally begins. How can I find the SAMLResponse so I can post it back to the homepage and finally get a logged session.

Comment: It;s not very clear what you try to achieve, mind explaining in more detail? In SAML terms, homepage = Service Provider, authentication page = Identity Provider. Where from are your redirecting with cURL ? Are you trying to implement your own SAML2 Service Provider?

Comment: @YiannisKakavas I am trying to mimic a login system for Moodle but our college uses a authentication page to first sign in to our university account, get a Authentication Token cookie, and then redirect back to Moodle homepage and automatically sign in using the Auth Token cookie

Comment: @YiannisKakavas So far I have been able to get to the point where I can check the credentials at the authentication page but then can't get the Auth token cookie since I need to POST to a SAML page with SAMLResponse post field